# Testing PDO code on 10 different database systems php

Tags: php, pdo

I have to make a web application that works on 10 different database systems Mysql, Sqlite, Oracle ... etc. - I need to check if my SQL is Compatible with all these databases.

I have made my code and tested on Mysql but how do I test it in the other databases? Should I install all these databases in my pc?

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: `is there an easier way to do it???` Probably not.....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your webapplication work on 10 different database systems, then you have to test it against those. If you only test against one of those 10, you do only know it works with one, not 10.

To test against all 10 database systems, you naturally need to install them and then run the database-test-suite you have for your application against those installments.

Which I think is pretty straight forward and easy. I can not imagine to make it more easy than just having those 10 database systems and run the testsuite against them.

If you do not have an automatic testsuite, create yourself one. Because manually testing against the databases - even necessary before you do the releases (or you let your users test that) - is too much work for every change you do in the software.

Comment: PHPUnit is a good way to test. Sounds easy. You can automate that and schedule tests with Jenkins CI, it will take care of the repetitive work like executing all tests when you commit a change or run the longer-running tests automatically at night. Automation is a key resource here.